# @Keyframes not working

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make a animation with `@keyframes`. But, the example don't work.

```css
.main{
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes change-bg-color {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: You have just configured the keyframes but haven't set the `animation` property to the element. It is like writing a function and never actually calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference it within your style declaration via the `animation` property:

```css
.main{
 animation: 5s change-bg-color;
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

@keyframes change-bg-color {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

MDN has a great overview of animations within CSS which will tell you all you need to know about configuring your animation to behave the way you want it to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation.

Comment: THank's for you help and the link of property Animation!